# Failure to forward a request with a session to a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, session

I'm trying to set an int value to request session like this...

```
        request.getSession().setAttribute("score", 0);          
        request.getRequestDispatcher("game.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

But `<% if(request.getAttribute("score") == null) %>` gives true, and I get `NullPointerException` when I try to use this data. What could be a possible cause for this? Thank you.

Comment: Seems you given a wrong path ? did you check that view is null or not ?

Comment: No its not null. the path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be..

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("score")
```

not

```
request.getAttribute("score")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setAttribute()` method is looking for an object in the second parameter, but you are providing a primitive type.  Try the following instead:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("score", new Integer(0));
```